# The program compiles using Visual Studio but clang and gcc cannot do it

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <int> exec(vector <int> &a, vector <int> &b) {
vector <int> res = a;
res.push_back(b[0]);
res.push_back(b[1]);
res.push_back(b[2]);
res.push_back(b[3]);
return res;
}


int main() {


vector <int> a1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, a2{ 5, 6, 7 , 8  };

std::packaged_task<vector <int>(vector <int>, vector <int>)> task(exec);
std::future<vector <int>> ret = task.get_future();            
std::thread th(std::move(task), a1, a2);  

th.detach();

vector <int> P1 = ret.get();


for (auto i = 0; i < P1.size(); ++i) {
    cout << P1[i];
}
cout << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Using -std=c++17 or -std=c++14 Clang always throws me one error:

```
In file included from Source.cpp:2:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\future:568:6: error: no
matching constructor for initialization of 'function<std::vector<int,
std::allocator<int> > (std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<int,
std::allocator<int> >)>'
: _Fn(_Fnarg)
  ^   ~~~~~~
```

And it also throws me a couple of warnings. The same thing goes for g++. I use Visual Studio 2015 and clang 6.0.0. What's the matter?

Answer (score 1):

You need `packaged_task` types match function types. In particular, since I assume you'd like to keep references for `exec`:

```
std::packaged_task<vector<int> (vector<int>&, vector<int>&)> task(exec);
std::future<vector <int>> ret = task.get_future();            
std::thread th(std::move(task), std::ref(a1), std::ref(a2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `exec` function takes references to vectors, but you define your task and future with an underlying function taking vector's copies. Either change `exec` or `task` definition.

I'd advise changing `exec` type to:

```
std::vector<int> exec(std::vector<int> base, std::vector<int> const &b) {
    base.push_back(b[0]);
    base.push_back(b[1]);
    base.push_back(b[2]);
    base.push_back(b[3]);
    return base;
}
```

and `task` to:

```
std::packaged_task<std::vector<int>(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> const&)> task(exec);
```